# Find Unique Characters and console.log() only the unique values in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

`console.log()` only the unique values from a string
`aaabbcddefffg`

What would be the output?

How do I write a program to display only the unique characters in a string which is entered by the user.

I've tried:

```js
function findUnique(str){
  let unique = "";
   
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){

    if(uniq.charAt(str[i] == ?){
      uniq += str[i]
    }
  }
  return unique;
}
```

Comment: And... where exactly are you stuck? If you really have no idea on how to write a program, you are encouraged to follow one of the countless free tutorials out there (Youtube etc.) and learn the basics.

Comment: Create `Map<value: char, counter: number>`. Iterate over string incrementing counter and at the end print only values from `Map` that have counter equal to `1`.

`char` is 1-length long string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'aaabbcddefffg'

const lettersMap = [...input].reduce((acc, e) => {   // create Map<string, number> that will store letter occurences
  acc[e] = acc[e] ? acc[e]+= 1 : 1
  return acc
}, {})

console.log('Letters map:', lettersMap)

Object.entries(lettersMap)
      .forEach(([letter, counter]) => {
        if (counter === 1) console.log('unique letter: ', letter) // print every letter that has counter equal 1 (is present once in input string)
      })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Answer (score 0):

First making an object where the keys are the letters and the values the times it happens, after that put all the letters that only occur once in a new string

```js
let res = '';
let tmp = {};

for (letter of 'aaabbcddefffg') {
  if (Object.keys(tmp).indexOf(letter) === -1) {
    tmp[letter] = 1;
  } else {
    tmp[letter]++;
  }
}

Object.entries(tmp).forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry[1] === 1) {
    res += entry[0]
  }
});

console.log(res)
```